# Move specific item to last position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let there is a model `Item` with attributes `id`, `name` and specific record in DB with name `'other'`.

How to get in single SQL query an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object with items sorted in way that `other` item is at last position?
As temporarily solution I used `Item.where.not(name: 'other') + Item.where(name: 'other')` but it results in 2 queries.

NB: it's not a real code but an extremely simplified example.

Comment: you could use  [Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: @Vinay, `Eager Loading` is for associated records. It's not such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with adding class method to `Item` model:

```
def self.sorted
  find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY (CASE name WHEN 'other' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC, id ASC")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like below will help - we read all `Item`s, and use slice to remove the `Item` with `name` equal to `other`, and append it back to array at the end.

```
a = Item.all.tap do |arr|
    arr << arr.slice!(arr.index { |t| t.name == "other"})
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right then you're looking for a SQL query, right? Then you could try something like that:

```
select id, name
from (
  select id, name, decode(name, 'other', 999, 1) as sort 
  from items
)
order by sort
```

I have no database right now to test the statement. But I think you get the idea.

Good luck